# Creating a new SAS variable that increments by first date of ID variable

Tags: sas

I'm trying to create a new variable that increments by days based on the first date of the ID variable in SAS.

I've been trying to use intck but to no avail. Below is my code:

```
DATA want;
    SET have;
    LENGTH NEWVAR 8.;
    by IDVAR DATEVAR;
    RETAIN NEWVAR ;

    if first.IDVAR then newvar =0 ;

     if first.DATEVAR then NEWVAR = intck('day',first.DATEVAR,'continuous')+1;

  RUN;
```

This is the dataset I'm looking to create:

```
IDVAR   DATEVAR NEWVAR
1   1-Jan-18    1
1   2-Jan-18    2
1   5-Jan-18    5
1   6-Jan-18    6
1   1-Feb-18    32
1   3-Feb-18    34
2   2-Jan-18    1
2   3-Jan-18    2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the first value in a separate variable that does not get updated.
`FIRST.<var>` is a special flag variable that will be either `0` or `1`.  It does not take on the value of the variable.

```
DATA want;
    SET have;
    LENGTH NEWVAR 8.;
    by IDVAR DATEVAR;

    RETAIN first_date_for_id ;

    if first.IDVAR then first_date_for_id = datevar ;

    NEWVAR = intck('day',datevar, first_date_for_id,'continuous')+1;
    label newvar = 'Days since id started';

    drop first_date_for_id;
  RUN;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked although I switched datevar and first_date_for_id to get the newvar to increment in the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close here. When referencing `first.datevar` the resulting value will be either 1 or 0 (i.e. true or false). Instead, you will need to `retain` the first datevar.

```
DATA want;
SET have;
LENGTH NEWVAR 8.;
by IDVAR DATEVAR;
RETAIN firstdate;

if first.IDVAR then do;
    firstdate = datevar;
end;     

NEWVAR = intck('day',firstdate,datevar)+1;

RUN;
```